# My 'deployed' contract still won't show up on Etherscan. Been about 1.5 hours

Tags: deployment, solidity, contract, hardhat, etherscan

need help figuring out why my supposedly 'deployed' contract will still not appear in Etherscan.

Overview:

- I used hardhat with following code and got back confirmation:

  $ npx hardhat run scripts/deployRoboPunksNFT.js --network rinkeby
  RoboPunksNFT deployed to: 0xaBDe0c1A9F7589f21818287287885a2Fef32E3f0
- Clearly, it confirms as fully deployed but when I check this contract address at Etherscan (Rinkeby)...nothing:  https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xaBDe0c1A9F7589f21818287287885a2Fef32E3f0
- The deployment script used:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const RoboPunksNFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("RoboPunksNFT");
  const roboPunksNFT = await RoboPunksNFT.deploy();
  await roboPunksNFT.deployed();
  console.log("RoboPunksNFT deployed to:", roboPunksNFT.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

- My hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");

dotenv.config();

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
        rinkeby: {
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE_KEY]
        },
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ETHERSCAN_KEY,
    }
};
```

I got so frustrated that I deployed it again (Code above is 2nd attempt/2nd deployed contract.  The first deployed contract address was at 0x9F6040234728493121BCB9A1EaFDBa5E494bB3ed.

Please let me know if anyone sees something that I missed.  Hopefully there's enuf info I've submitted here to determine...
Thanks very much!

Comment: I can see it there already. Sometimes it just takes blockchain explorers a longer time to process transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  Rinkeby happened to be down for 6 whole hours.  But once it came back up, had 2 freshly deployed contracts on Rinkeby ready to go...